# changing / selecting a value in a dropdown box .. using Geb

Tags: groovy, geb

As a Geb Newb, this is confusing. In attempting to click on a combo/dropdown box, I'm getting the following error:

"geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'pages.ecomm.NewEnrollmentPage -> countrySelected: geb.module.Select' is not present"

**1. page looks like this**
[image]

**2. here is my source:**

**3. test spec code, for selecting dropdown. Error appears to indicate the 'countrySelected' content/element isn't on the page? Or I'm not even on the page?**

NewEnrollmentPage.groovy

```
import geb.Page
import geb.module.Select

class NewEnrollmentPage extends Page {


    static url = "/shop/spring/enrollment/start/78867?tagCountry=AN&customerType=D&tagLang=ENU&__checkbox_isPC=true&UNI_TODAY=true&__checkbox_UNI_TODAY=true&clearSession=1"
                // "/shop/spring/enrollment/product/landing"
                // below for mwebs (non-prod) --->v

    //At Checker
    static at  = {
        title == "Enrollment"
    }

    static content = {
        // <navigatorName ><options map> <actual navigator>
        CrInitOrdButton(wait: true) { driver.findElement(By.id($("[id='toProductsPage']"))) }
        countrySelected { $("#countrySelected").module(Select) }
        //Options Map
        /* wait : true
         * required : false
         *
         *
         *
         */
    }
}
```

test.groovy

```
class test extends smoke.ecomm.resource.ShopBootStrap {

   def "Select Country"() {
        given:
            at NewEnrollmentPage
        when: "select United States for Country"
            **countrySelected.value('US')**

    .
    .
    .

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect. You are selecting using id of `countrySelected` but that's the name of your element and its id is actually `countries`. So you need to change your content definition to either:

```
countrySelected { $("#countries").module(Select) }
```

or

```
countrySelected { $(name: "countrySelected").module(Select) }
```

Comment: neither is working?  how do I ensure I'm on the page?

Comment: You have an at checker defined in your page class so as long as the condition is correct you are on the right page otherwise you would get a different error thrown from `at()` call. Does your page load synchronously (is served from a server side template) or asynchronously (is a single page app)?

Comment: I'm using 'at' to confirm page, however, when I get to the line, which should change the value to 'US' nothing? what's an example to sroll to the 'US' value in the dropdown and select?

Comment: **Modified original example to change the dropdown to US/United States **

Comment: Maybe you just follow the ['Select' module documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#code-select-code) and set the value via `countrySelected.selected = 'US'`. BTW, you could rename `countrySelected` to just `country` (like the label on your page), then the expression would not look quite as strange and repetitious. I think `country.selected = 'US'` reads easier.